# Ajax.BeginForm can't submit the form properly

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have a form which is supported by `Ajax.BeginForm`. There are two input fields in the form and additionally one hidden field.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("InsertMissingItems","MissingItem", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "itemList" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Statu, new { id = "hdnStatu" })
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group" lang="tr">
                        @Html.Label("Ürün Adı", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 text-left" })
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name,
                                new List<SelectListItem> {
                                    new SelectListItem {
                                       Text="CSS",
                                       Value="1",
                                    },
                                    new SelectListItem {
                                       Text="HTML",
                                       Value="2",
                                    },
                                }, "Kategori Seçiniz", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" lang="tr">
                        @Html.Label("Miktar", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 text-left" })
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = 1 })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                            <button class="btn btn-success col-lg-4" type="submit" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Validation(@((int)Enums.MissingItem.Add))"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Ekle</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

When I submit the form, the hidden field `@Html.HiddenFor` and `@Html.DropDownListFor` values are being captured correctly and this values are assigned to my model via `model => model.Statu` and `model => model.Name` expressions. However, the value of `@Html.TextBoxFor` with the expression `model => model.Quantity` is not being captured correcly and when I receive the model at the controller side, I can see that the `Quantity` is set to **0**. What can be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add the at symbol before the type and min as well. [at]Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { [at]class = "form-control", [at]type = "number", [at]min = 1 }) and it should work

Comment: I usually encountered this problem when the element is outside the <form> tag or it is read-only, disabled, you might check these possibilities.

Comment: I have just noticed that when I removed the `type` attribute from `TextBoxForm`, it suddenly worked. So, what does it mean?

Comment: [at]Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { [at]class = "form-control", [at]type = "number", [at]min = "1" }) this is the correct sintax

Comment: @OzanYurtsever check my second comment, you need to at the at symbol before type and min and also add the number 1 between quotation marks like this "1"

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez, it didn't work.